# After Counting data how can i move to next textField. Where to put code to resign first responder?

Tags: ios, swift2

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
   return newLength <= 1


}
```

Where should i resign firstTextfield ? I need to move from one text field to another textfield as user enter 1 character only

Comment: you can resign it in the above posted method. Check for the textfield, and then check for the textfieldtext, if it is greater than 1, resign it!!

Comment: @Davin Does my answer helped you out?

Comment: The answer by Shahzad Ali, just about covers it. Add tags to the fields and then in the delegate methods decide where and how you want to make the next field become first responder. Maybe create a method that takes the current tag as a parameter or some variant.

Comment: yes..But i have to type to time . For example When i enter first  character . it check and next time i type character it check again then go to second textField .. here i have two type again to get value..

Comment: @Davin I updated my answer as per your requirements. Now you will not need to type for two times. I hope you will also accept it ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign tags to your textFields in a sequence you want them to get active one after the other. Get your next textField based on your current textField tag and make it first responder. Here is the code for this.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    if(newLength < 1){
        return true
    }else if (newLength == 1){

        let textfield = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1)

        let delayInSeconds = 0.5
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            textfield?.becomeFirstResponder();
        }
        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be so complex.

Don't bother with the delegate. Instead use an IBAction attached to the UITextField's editingChanged action.

The code below assumes that `textField[0]` is only allowed to hold 1 character. `textField[1]` will become first responder as soon as the character is entered.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!

    @IBAction func editingChangedAction(sender: UITextField) {
        if sender === textFields[0] && sender.text?.characters.count >= 1 {
            textFields[1].becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

}
```

The user could still paste more than one character into the field. If you are worried about that, you can trim the text of the field inside the if block.

Comment: Perfect ..Well other methods works too ..This is easiest one.. Thanks